# Concating multiple images in a Single Image in JAVA

Tags: java, png, jpeg

I have multiple small images like stickers and i need to concat it into a single large image in A4 size for print.If a page completed by images it should create new large image and continue the concat process of the stickers.Is it possible in java kindly help me out.

Comment: What have you tried till now? It would be good to see your effort, so that some one can correct you, instead of writing a code for you. The methods and classes you need are `ImageIO.read()`, `BufferedImage` and `ImageIO.write()`.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in Java?

Comment: Because my entire project in java so that i have to do that in java.i cant change that platform for this thing that's why i am asking friends.